# Xcode 14 -How to Open Custom iOS Target Properties (info.plist) as Source Code?

Tags: xcode, info.plist

**How can I open Custom iOS Target Properties as Source Code?** I want to c+p items there.

I'm using Xcode 14 and I have a bunch of SKAdNetowrkItems that I need to add. When I'm in the navigator -> open info.plist as Source Code -> manually add all of the items, it's there.

[image]

But when I check in Custom iOS Target Properties the SKAdNetowrkItems doesn't appear so they aren't synced

[image]

Comment: Strangely no one has commented on this till now!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across with something like this.

It looks like that `Custom iOS Target Properties` (Target > Info) is auto generated every time which makes the properties unsynced.

**Solution:**

Project > Target `Build Settings` then search for "Packaging", look for `Generate Info.plist File`.

If in bold just press delete or manually set to No.
[image]

After doing that you will notice that the `Info.plist` from project navigator and the `Custom iOS Target Properties` are synced.

You can then right click the `Info.plist` *Open as Source Code*.

Comment: I've never heard of this method before, hmmmm. I'm going to try this tomorrow on a new project to see what happens. If it works I'll accept :)